# Selecting specific text from text file, BASH scripting

Tags: bash, text-extraction, pbs

I've been running simulations on a cluster and I would like to check temporary results by going through all cluster nodes and to copy all the files I need.

What I've been trying to do is to extract job ID and node name as a string from a text file that looks like this after typing `qstat -rn u djsavic`:

```
fermi: 
                                                                               Req'd    Req'd      Elap
Job ID               Username    Queue    Jobname          SessID NDS   TSK    Memory   Time   S   Time
-------------------- ----------- -------- ---------------- ------ ----- ------ ------ -------- - --------
59281.fermi          djsavic     xlarge   Smith2            30676     1      2    --  96:00:00 R 24:19:14
    fermi-node08/1+fermi-node08/0
59282.fermi          djsavic     xlarge   Smith2            30686     1      2    --  96:00:00 R 24:18:56
    fermi-node08/3+fermi-node08/2
59283.fermi          djsavic     xlarge   Smith2            30700     1      2    --  96:00:00 R 24:18:56
    fermi-node08/5+fermi-node08/4
59284.fermi          djsavic     xlarge   Smith2            30729     1      2    --  96:00:00 R 24:21:09
    fermi-node08/7+fermi-node08/6
59285.fermi          djsavic     xlarge   Smith2             9076     1      2    --  96:00:00 R 24:19:24
    fermi-node07/1+fermi-node07/0
59286.fermi          djsavic     xlarge   Smith2             9078     1      2    --  96:00:00 R 24:19:23
    fermi-node07/3+fermi-node07/2
59287.fermi          djsavic     xlarge   Smith2             9079     1      2    --  96:00:00 R 24:19:41
    fermi-node07/5+fermi-node07/4
59288.fermi          djsavic     xlarge   Smith2             9080     1      2    --  96:00:00 R 24:19:57
    fermi-node07/7+fermi-node07/6
```

In reality, the list is longer, around 80 lines.

What I need are jobs ID and node name, so I could copy files e.g. from directory `fermi-node08/59281/` to some `/location`

After a lot of digging and searching throught the internet, so far, I did something like this:

```
for i in `qstat -rn -u djsavic`; do
    for j in `echo $i|grep fermi`; do
             echo $j|sed -r 's/(.{12}).*/\1/'|sed  's/.fermi//';
    done;
done
```

and what I get is a list like this:

```
fermi:
59281
fermi-node08
59282
fermi-node08
59283
fermi-node08
59284
fermi-node08
59285
fermi-node07
59286
fermi-node07
59287
fermi-node07
59288
fermi-node07
```

At this point, I would like to copy files from all `/fermi-node##/JobID/` to a desired location and also to remove this `fermi:` from the top of the list. I am new to bash scripting and I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with the final step.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

If your input is in that form (the records are in two lines) and three header lines, you can extract the information you need with this

```
$ awk 'NR>3{ if(!(NR%2)) {sub(".fermi","",$1); n=$1}
              else {sub("/.*","",$1); print $1"/"n}}' file

fermi-node08/59281
fermi-node08/59282
fermi-node08/59283
fermi-node08/59284
fermi-node07/59285
fermi-node07/59286
fermi-node07/59287
fermi-node07/59288
```

you can use this in a while loop for your further processing such as

```
$ while read f; do echo $f; done < <(awk ...)
```

just replace `echo $f` with what you want to do.

UPDATE: if the header lines are not fixed, this may be more robust

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]*\.fermi/ {sub(".fermi","",$1); n=$1; next}
                       n{sub("/.*","",$1); print $1"/"n;n=""}' file
```

Comment: How do you stop the output from having `--------------------/Job` at the top?

Comment: I tried it, and my output looks like this:                                                `59281.fermi/--------------------`
`59282.fermi/fermi-node08/1-node08/0`
`59283.fermi/fermi-node08/3-node08/2`
`59284.fermi/fermi-node08/5-node08/4` .... I would like to get `fermi-node08/59281` etc.

Comment: @DjordjeSavic, What version of AWK is on your system?  I'm using GNU Awk 4.0.1 under Linux Mint 17.1 and it outputs `--------------------/Job` and then the `fermi-node08/59281` lines using karakfa's `awk` command line.

Comment: Never mind, this did it: `awk 'NR>4{ if(NR%2) {sub(".fermi","",$1); n=$1} else {sub("/.*","",$1); print $1"/"n}}' file`

Comment: The robust version is nice! +1

Comment: I realized that my final output needs to be like this: `/scratch/fermi-node08/djsavic/Smith2/59281*` I found a way to extract model name `Smith2`, It is fourth word in the sixth row. How do I add this /scratch/ and $model into your solution?

Comment: Set m=$4 in the first block and use it in the second block print.

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to solve this. How do I instert `/scratch/` at the beginning and `/djsavic/Smith2/` between `fermi-node##` and `JobID`, and how to put `*` at the end?